# Capture the data from array json response using typescript

Tags: typescript, rest

```
{
"items": [
  {
"ContestId": 300100183354726,
"ContestNumber": "CDRM_11102",
"ContestName": "New Contest 58428129",
"Description": null,
"OwnerId": 100010032636167,
"StartDate": "2019-12-12T00:00:00+00:00",
"EndDate": "2019-12-22T00:00:00+00:00",
"KPIId": 300100180907483,
"CreatedBy": "SALES_MGR",
"CreationDate": "2019-12-12T09:24:26+00:00",
"LastUpdatedBy": "SALES_MGR",
"LastUpdateDate": "2019-12-12T09:24:26.081+00:00",
"LastUpdateLogin": "94FD310D04952F1BE05369B3F20A9266",
"ObjectVersionNumber": 1,
"ConflictId": 0,
"OwnerName": "Todd Beeler",
"OwnerNumber": "100010032636167",
"OwnerUniqueName": "Todd Beeler",
"KPIName": "Appointments Completed",
"KPINumber": "CDRM_6",
"KPIDescription": null
}
],
"count": 1,
"hasMore": false,
"limit": 25,
"offset": 0,
"links": [
  {
"rel": "self",
"href": "https://fuscdrmsmc217-fa-ext.us.oracle.com:443/crmRestApi/resources/11.13.18.05/contests",
"name": "contests",
"kind": "collection"
}
],
}
```

When I try :

```
contestNumber = await restResponce.responceJSON["items[1].ContestNumber"]
```

The result is undefined. Please help w\how can I fetch the contest number.

My Library :

```js
export let restResponce = { 
    "responceJSON" : {},
    "responceCODE" : 0,
    "responceTEXT" : "", 
    "requestedValues" : {}
    };
```

Comment: How do you fill the `responceJSON` object in `restResponce`? It looks like the `dict` is not getting filled with data

Comment: `{}` is not a helpful type for `responceJSON`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
var json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
document.write(json.items[0].ContestNumber);
```

This should work!